# sql join two cells without criteria

Tags: sql

in SSMS, when I run

```
      select 1 as A, 2 as B
```

I get a table with one row and two cells.

When I run

```
select avg(column1) from table1 where company like '%3m%'and Column2!=0
```

I get a number x,

and when I run

```
select avg(column3) from table1 where company like '%3m%'and Column4!=0
```

I get another number y.

I wonder how can use a single query to put x and y together in a one row table?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT AVG(column1) FROM table1 WHERE company LIKE '%3m%'and Column2!=0) AS A,
    (SELECT AVG(column3) FROM table1 WHERE company LIKE '%3m%'and Column4!=0) AS B
```

Comment: Thank you! That's simple and quick!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    AVG(CASE WHEN Column2 !=0 THEN Column1 END) AS A,
    AVG(CASE WHEN Column4 !=0 THEN Column3 END) AS B
FROM Table1
WHERE Company LIKE '%3m%' AND (Column2!=0 OR Column4 !=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can

```
SELECT avg(case when Column2!=0 then column1 else NULL end)
     , avg(case when Column4!=0 then column3 else NULL end)
FROM   table1
WHERE  company LIKE '%3m%'
```

Answer (score 0):

When you execute a `select` statement, you get a *result set*, not a *table*. For you question, you might try constructing a suitable *discriminent function* using the `case` function as follows:

```
select avg(case when column2 != 0 then column1 else null end) as col1_average ,
       avg(case when column4 != 0 then column3 else null end) as col3_average
from table1
where company like '%3m%'
```